# Cross browser image hover effect that works with Masonry jquery plug-in?

Tags: image, hover, fade, jquery-masonry, flickr

Wondering if anybody could help me out. I have the Masonry jquery plug-in which is laying out a set of images and when you zoom in or out in the browser, they change place to fit more/less of the images on the screen. Is there a way to, when i hover over these images, they would fade to black and a description of the image would appear in it's place.

A bit like http://www.flickr.com/ but rather than the small box at the bottom when you hover on an image, a box that covers the whole image and each seperate image can have a seperate description.

Answer (score 0):

some possible hover effects is like Image effects, like grayscale, blur, sepia, etc. I still haven't figure out the best hover effect that have fix height/width.